# Generate one pdf per page with jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

(Using Jaspersoft Studio 6.6.0, no Jasper Server yet)
My dataset looks like this

```
id|question1|question2|question3
1 |answer1.1|answer1.2|answer1.3
8 |answer8.1|answer8.2|answer8.3
```

The report is designed to show one row per page

```
Page 1:
<------- Header-------->
<--------ID:1---------->
Question 1:
[answer1.1]

Question 2:
[answer1.2]

Question 3:
[answer1.3]
<-------Footer------->

Page 2:
<------- Header-------->
<--------ID:8---------->
Question 1:
[answer8.1]

Question 2:
[answer8.2]

Question 3:
[answer8.3]
<-------Footer------->
```

If i generate the report as PDF, i get one PDF with as many pages as there are rows.

But what i need would be to have as many seperate PDF files as there are rows. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to do that. I don't know if you are a programmer but I've already exported multiple reports using java. You can simply loop through your rows and each time you loop you export your file using the ID or something like that as a file name ( Otherwise you'll either get an error because filename already existed or you'll overwrite the old one and you'll end up with the last row only depends on your export configuration)

Otherwise you can just simply use a tool to split your PDF, there are literally tons of them and they're even online. So, you can choose from these solutions whatever fits you best.